# After the upgrade to 13.10 I only see social media results in the finder

Tags: unity, unity-dash

I've upgraded to Ubuntu 13.10. If I now click the Ubuntu logo the default is that it only searches in social media. I cannot find my programs any more!

Answer (score 0):

In the dash, there's a button on the top-right corner that says "Filter results." Click on it to check if perhaps your results had been filtered somehow.